# Error while deleting field in geopackage using QGIS 3.4.2

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have a geopackage file and I would like to delete a field. I run into unexpected behavior.

My process:

- Open QGIS
- Add gepackage layer
- Open attribute table
- Enable Edit mode
- Click remove field

[image: example1]

- select the field and click ok
- Stop edit
- Save the changes

[image: example2]

after I press save, my entire attribute table is gone.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in QGIS?

QGIS 3.4.2

Comment: Try upgrading to 3.4.10. from memory this issue was already fixed

Comment: I just installed the 3.4 Long Term Support (3.4.10) version and tried again to no avail....

Comment: I was able to obtain the desired result using the "drop field(s)" algorithm from the processing toolbox

Comment: What if you close the attribute table and open it again? QGIS has a longstanding issue with open attribute tables not staying up-to-date when you change the source data.